# PL/SQL procedure for inner join and where clause

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsqldeveloper

I want to create PL/SQL stored procedure for following query:

```
SELECT order_id, order_date,  customer_id
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.customer_id = Customers.customer_id
WHERE order_id = xyz;
```

I want to pass `order_id` as input parameter in stored procedure. 
Can someone please share the PL/SQL code for this?

Comment: What do you want the procedure to do?

Comment: I want the procedure to display the result of above mentioned query.

Comment: Display result = return a ref cursor?

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_test(p1 IN NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS

    s_query_stmt     VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR);
    r1               VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);
    r2               VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);
    r3               VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);

   BEGIN

   s_query_stmt := 'Select order_id, order_date, customer_id 
                    From Orders inner join Customers 
                    On Orders.customer_id = Customers.customer_id
                   WHERE order_id = :x )';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE s_query_stmt INTO r1, r2, r3 USING p1;
   return 'x';

  END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple form of a procedure that would return those values is like this (:

```
create or replace procedure retrieve_order_values(
  p_order_id IN Orders.order_id%type
, p_order_date OUT Orders.order_date%type
, p_customer_id OUT Orders.customer_id%type
)
is
begin
  select order_date, customer_id
  into p_order_date, p_customer_id
  from orders
  where order_id = p_order_id;
end retrieve_order_values;
```

Please note that you do not need the join to the `Customers` table to retrieve the customer_id.

Comment: The reason why I am using join is I may need data from 3-4 tables in future.